# Should I remove facebook pixel TAG after having facebook conversion api TAG?(both on GTM)

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel, facebook-conversions-api

I created a web container and sever container,
and I had created the facebook CAPI tag for tracking on the server container,
I can see in the progress, it does not need to create a facebook Pixel.

but my current setup was retaining the facebook pixel tag on client side.
I know facebook pixel is required for the facebook CAPI tag,
but what about the facebook pixel tag on web container?

Because I can see the client side tracking may be affected by the anti-tracking feature,
and server side works well.
Should I remove the client side tracking, only do the tracking from server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Facebook itself recommends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/guides/end-to-end-implementation#pick-your-integration-type) to not deploy a server-only implementation because you can lose many events that are "browser native", like PageView or ViewContent. The official recommendation is to adopt a redundant setup, sending events via both Pixel and Conversions API. Facebook has the ability to deduplicate events and you get more precise and optimized conversions.

Comment: I realize the linked documentation may have updated since posting the answer, but when I go there it says nothing about possibly losing "browser native" (what does that event mean) events. If you send the the same events (including PageView and ViewContent) to Conversions API, why is the Pixel still needed? I've been trying to find the answer to that question. Facebooks docs doesn't explain why.